# Magento2.3 Could not open input file update/cron.php does not exist

Tags: magento2, cron

I have a Magento2.3 based website and I did a mass update of products 2 days ago. However still at the top of the Magento admin panel I see a yellow bar that says

```
Task "Update attributes for 50 selected products": 5 item(s) have been scheduled for update.
```

I tried running cron manually on the command line via this command:

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

However after a few minutes it still does not clear.
I have the below cron jobs listed/setup when I look at crontab -e on the command line

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.3 /var/www/***/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/***/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.3 /var/www/***/update/cron.php >> /var/www/***/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.3 /var/www/***/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/***/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

So I am not sure what the issue is. I think I am missing the /update/cron.php file ??

Also I do not seem to get any automated emails such as the back in stock emails which I believe are triggered via Cron.

When I look in my cron_schedule database I see a lot of rows that say

```
Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is missed at 2020-12-04 15:50:00 
Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is missed at 2020-12-04 13:15:00
Cron Job consumers_runner is missed at 2020-12-04 10:44:00
Class Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Consumer\Config\CompositeReader\Interceptor does not exist
```

any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running:

`php bin/magento cron:install`

This writes directly to your default crontab file.

Comment: Yes and I get 
Crontab has already been generated and saved